# Apple sign in get user data with access token

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

I have a question about apple sign in. I just implemented an apple sign in, and I found that I received an identity token, access token, and refresh token. It seems that the identity token has user information in the json web token. I am wondering how I can use the access symbol to receive user information? Facebook and also Google has own endpoint where if I send in that endpoint access token I retrieve user data. Does apple sign in has something similar?

Thanks for the information

Comment: You need to call token rest api and you will get json with id_token field. This is a JWT field which can be decoded with apple public key. https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys

Answer (score 0):

To get the user_data(email,name) I am using the following code:

```
if id_token:
            decoded = jwt.decode(id_token, "", verify=False)
            response_data.update(
                {"email": decoded["email"], "name": decoded["name"]}
            ) if "email" in decoded else None
            response_data.update({"uid": decoded["sub"]}) if "sub" in decoded else None
```

Here, after successfully receiving id token from "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token" just decode the id_token and get data from it using the appropiriate fields.
Hope this solves your problem of how to get user data from apple social login.

Comment: id_token does not contain user data just email. User data are available only at first-sign and only as post field `user` when redirected from authorization to your redirect_uri See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple#3331292

Answer (score -4):

Apple's system is basically like `oAuth` ... see https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: yeah. But if I have an access token which endpoint from Apple should I use to get user data? :)

Comment: Apple states that the access token itself is not yet used. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/tokenresponse Only the id token is used.